# Как правильно связать домен iis и конкретный порт на Iis

Tags: сервер, хостинг, iis, домен, vps

Есть арендованный впс(winserver2012), на нем стоит иис, сейчас там хостится допустим 5 сайтов

- хттп:\ип......:порт №80
- хттп:\ип......:порт №82
- хттп:\ип......:порт №85

---

в настройках доменного имени у регистратора, в данном случае можно указать только ип, без порта, только ип. Далее если я приду просто по ип,я прийду на основной открытый порт, т.е. 80
мой сайт на 85 к которому я хочу привязать домен, но с домена переходит все равно на основной т.е. на 80

как сделать так что бы клиента закидывать на тот порт куда ему нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак вы это не сделаете. Просто потому что домен - это синоним для ip-адреса а не для пары из адреса и порта.

Но, учитывая что протокол HTTP/1.1 вышел уже давным-давно, вы можете просто прописать в IIS каждому сайту его доменное имя:

[image]

Имя домена передается браузером в заголовке Host, и IIS умеет использовать его для выбора нужного сайта.

Comment: пробовал, по факту не отрабатывает, я бы сказал если так при переходе по домену попадаешь на 80 порт, без этого вообще ошибку кидает.
мне объяснили что можно создать правило в брандмауэре, для домена прописать порт

Comment: @AleksanderTozik вот у того, кто вам это сказал, и спрашивайте как это сделать.